# Exercise 15.7 in Hartshorne's Deformation theory

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $F,G$ be two covariant functors from $\mathcal{C}\rightarrow\text{Sets}$, where $\mathcal{C}$ is the category of Artinian local $k$-algebras, where $k$ is a fixed alg. closed field.

Let $F\twoheadrightarrow G$ be a strongly surjective morphism of functors (ie, "smooth"), let $h_S\twoheadrightarrow F$ be a versal family for $F$, and $h_R\twoheadrightarrow G$ a miniversal family for $G$.

In this situation, the image of the identity $id_S$ under the composition $h_S(S)\twoheadrightarrow F(S)\twoheadrightarrow G(S)$ can be lifted to an element of $f\in h_R(S)$, giving a map $f : R\rightarrow S$ inducing a morphism of functors
$$h_S\rightarrow h_R$$
which is compatible with the map $F\twoheadrightarrow G$.

However, I've thought about this for the last two hours, and I don't see why this map $h_S\rightarrow h_R$ needs to be strongly surjective.

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Note that you can also play the same game as you did with $f$, by looking at the diagram of functors evaluated at $R$, to produce a map $g : S\rightarrow R$ such that if $\eta : h_S\rightarrow F$ is the versal family, then
$$h_R\stackrel{g^*}{\rightarrow}h_S\stackrel{f^*}{\rightarrow} h_R\stackrel{\eta}{\rightarrow}G$$
is equal to $\eta$. Since miniversal families are unique up to isomorphism, this implies that $f^*g^*$ is an automorphism! (not necessarily the identity, unless $\eta$ was actually universal).

At the level of rings, this implies that we get maps
$$R\stackrel{f}{\rightarrow}S\stackrel{g}{\rightarrow}R$$
such that the composition $gf$ is an isomorphism. At this point, it's purely formal to check that $h_S\stackrel{f^*}{\rightarrow} h_R$ is strongly surjective.